How to Create a Gradient Selection Along a Curved Mesh Object in Geometry Nodes?
Using Blender's Geometry Nodes, I'm trying to create a gradient selection mask that follows the length of a curved mesh object. The gradient should smoothly transition from 0 to 1, starting at one end of the shape and following the tangent of the curve to the other end. I’m not sure how to get the gradient to follow the curvature of the mesh.



If you start with a curve, you can just capture the factor of the spline:

Otherwise you can e.g. find the bottom (lowest z coordinate), mark it, blur with a lot of iterations, then use Attribute Statistic + Map Range to normalize to 0..1 range:

Perhaps a bit silly, as you could use a "shortest path" functionality instead, or together with blur:


That works well, thanks! Although, it was a little hard to follow with the hidden node sockets
